# how to add the splitview in the tab bar application in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want to add the split view in the one tab bar item. i have added that but when i click on the that tab bar item, the tabbar get disappear.

so I want to know the correct way of adding the spitview in the tabbaritem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but since I stumbled over this question, someone else might as well...

The `UISplitViewController` class is designed to be run as the top view controller and does not support being a child of either `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController`. If you need a nested split view have a look at [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad)